# Get values with Zabbix web scenario

Tags: zabbix

I try to get values from a webscenario check in Zabbix with the use of regular expressions. Just like: http://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-2-2-features-part-6-returning-values-from-webpages/2256/

I would like to set this feature using the Zabbix Webclient but I can't find out how to do this.

The purpose is to monitor free diskspace of a hosting package instead of the whole server disk.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Frank

Comment: You should create an item of type "Zabbix agent" or "Zabbix agent (active)" with key web.page.regexp[], similar to the one on the blog post. What kind of problem are you experiencing?

Comment: HI there, you helped me already a lot by pointing me that I need to create a item. I tried to create a Webscenario. But unfortunately I still can't get it working. I now have the following in the key field:
web.page.regexp[www.domain.nl,script.php,80,"free:([0-9]+)",,\1]

The script I try to access reports the following:

Total: 102400MB ,100GB
Free: 96854MB ,95GB
free:96854

I try to get the value behind the word "free:"

For the rest I tried active and normal agent, i said the data type is numeric(decimal) and for the rest all default.

Hpe you can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: sniff the traffic, be sure you really get the text you are expecting. or change the regexp to (.+), you should catch whatever you receive. Your regexp should work though: `$ echo 'Total: 102400MB ,100GB Free: 96854MB ,95GB free:96854' | perl -lane '/free:(\d+)/;print $1;'
96854`

Comment: When you say that it does not work, how does it manifest? Does the item become not supported? Does the item return any value at all? Could you please show the output of the following shell command: `$ zabbix_agentd -t 'web.page.regexp[www.domain.nl,script.php,80,"free:([0-9]+)",,\1]'` (with the correct item key parameters)?

Comment: Thx for your comments. I tried but still can't get it to work. I got the following msg when  I user the web.page.get command:    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>GET to /index.html not supported.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 PHP/5.3.28 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: Necroposting a bit... but in the latest attempt you are getting error 404, page not found. A quick guess - you tried to obfuscate the actual script name (as `script.php`), but did not replace it for your test.